# Text rearrangement in same text file in different position with some changes made on it and delete some particular text using python

Tags: python, string, replace

There are some inputs

```
1. "Want to learn more? (link to https://www.google.com) Click here."

2  "Want to learn more? (link to https://https://www.google.com) website."
```

Expected Outputs Respectively:

```
1 "Want to learn more? [Click here] (https://www.google.com)."

2 "Want to learn more? [website] (https://https://www.google.com)."
```

Explanation:

I want to delete `link to` in the URL and text after the `()` rearrange before the `()` with cotted with `[]`.

Comment: what did you try? Show your code and full error message? I would try `text.find()` or `text.split()` with `(link to ` and `)` to get 3 elements - text before `(link to`, text between `(link to` and `)`, text after `)` - and then there is no problem to create new text with expected output. Or you can use `regex` for this.

Comment: import re
with open(r'C:\Users\test.txt') as infile, open(r'C:\test1.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "[":
            copy = True
        if copy: # flipped to include end, as Dan H pointed out
            outfile.write(line)
        if line.strip() == "]":
            copy = False

Comment: always add code, data and error messages in question, not in comment. It will be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Without using `regex` you can use `text.split()` to split to parts which you can later rearange. I code I display these parts as `a,b,c,d`

```
text = '''
1. "Want to learn more? (link to https://www.google.com) Click here."
2  "Want to learn more? (link to https://https://www.google.com) website."
'''

for line in text.splitlines():
    if line:
        #print(line)
        a, b = line.split('(link to ')
        b, c = b.split(') ')
        c, d = c.split('.')
        print(' a:', a)
        print(' b:', b)
        print(' c:', c)
        print(' d:', d)
        print('{}[{}] ({}).{}'.format(a, c, b, d))
```

Result:

```
 a: 1. "Want to learn more? 
 b: https://www.google.com
 c: Click here
 d: "
1. "Want to learn more? [Click here] (https://www.google.com)."
 a: 2  "Want to learn more? 
 b: https://https://www.google.com
 c: website
 d: "
2  "Want to learn more? [website] (https://https://www.google.com)."
```

---

The same with `re.split()`

```
text = '''
1. "Want to learn more? (link to https://www.google.com) Click here."
2  "Want to learn more? (link to https://https://www.google.com) website."
'''

import re

for line in text.splitlines():
    if line:
        a = re.split('(.*)\(link to (.*)\) (.*)(\.")', line)
        print(a)
        print('{}[{}] ({}){}'.format(a[1], a[3], a[2], a[4]))
```